# How to calculate target address in relocatable elf

Tags: linker, embedded, loader, elf

In the standard elf , the relocation entry is of the following type  :

```
typedef struct {
Elf32_Addr r_offset;
Elf32_Word r_info;
Elf32_Word r_addend;
} Elf32_Rela;
```

Here I understand that the r_offset tells the memory location to apply the relocation . However , I have not been able to understand through any link I gone through so far regarding how to combine r_info and r_addend to get a final target address.

Can someone please help me understand this or provide a good layman level link that I can go through ?